# Is it possible to add TODAY + 2 in reports?

Tags: reports-api

I want to use- Validity_Date__c GREATER OR EQUAL TODAY+2 in reports. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking to add a filter to your report where you wish to only see records that have a `Validity_Date__c` that is >= today + 2 days?

Answer (score 1):

In a report, you can specify "greater than next 2 days" as a filter. In SOQL, you can specify "> NEXT_N_DAYS:2" in a filter criteria. Note that in both cases, you need to not use "greater or equal to", because that is the same as "greater than today". The reason why is that NEXT_N_DAYS:2 expands to a date range that runs from midnight following the current day for 48 hours after that.